# Prove that bilinear form is not an inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that $$\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle: \mathbf{R}[X]_{\leqslant 3}\times \mathbf{R}[X]_{\leqslant 3}\to\mathbf{R}:[q,r]\mapsto q(-1)r(-1)+q(0)r(0)+q(1)r(1)$$ is not a real inner product on $\mathbf{R}[X]_{\leqslant 3}$.

This should be very simple, but I can't see how this is done.. I tried proving that $\langle q,q\rangle\not\implies q=0$ but that doesn't work too. Could someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $q(x)=x(x^2-1)$. Then $q(0)=q(1)=q(-1)=0$, hence $\langle q,q\rangle=0$, but $q \ne 0$.